# How to issue a specified SQL when Spring Framework starts a transaction

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions, spring-mybatis

I am developing a Java application with Spring Framework and MyBatis (`mybatis-spring`).
In my application, I am using separated RDBMS schemas for each user. You can switch a schema with a SQL `SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION` in the business logic.

In some RDBMS, `SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION` can only be issued as the first statement (ex. [IBM Db2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0011139.html)), or be issued before a transaction started (ex. [Hitachi HiRDB](http://itdoc.hitachi.co.jp/manuals/3020/3020645710e/W4570207.HTM))

So I want to issue `SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION` just before/after the Spring Framework starts a transaction.
Note that I am using `@Transactional` annotation to control transactions.

I found the `TransactionSynchronization` class that has `beforeCommit()` to run some logic before a transaction committed, but it's too late to run `SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION`.

#### Example

For example, if you have the following code,

- When you send a request on `/postA`, you should issue `SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION` on (A).
- When you send a request on `/postB`, you should issue `SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION` on (B), but should not issue it on (A).

Simple annotation like `@Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional *)")` doesn't work for this requirement, because it cannot distinguish two situations above.

```java
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    TestServiceA serviceA;
    @Autowired
    TestServiceB serviceB;

    @PostMapping("/postA")
    public void postA() {
        serviceA.insertA();
    }

    @PostMapping("/postB")
    public void postB() {
        serviceB.insertB();
    }
}

@Service
public class TestServiceA {

    @Autowired
    ItemDao itemDao;

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void insertA() {
        // (A)
        itemDao.insert(someItem);
    }
}

@Service
public class TestServiceB {

    @Autowired
    ItemDao itemDao;

    @Autowired
    TestServiceA serviceA;

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void insertB() {
        // (B)
        serviceA.insertA();
        itemDao.insert(someItem);
    }
}
```

#### Question

How can I run some logic when the Spring Framework starts a transaction, to issue `SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION`?

Comment: You can use spring AOP concept here.https://www.journaldev.com/2583/spring-aop-example-tutorial-aspect-advice-pointcut-joinpoint-annotations

Comment: @Developer You can identify the method annotated with `@Transactional` with Spring AOP, but I think you cannot detect the start of a transaction with AOP features. I have added a sample code.